# SQLite analyzing cursor data

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm coding a quiz and record individual answers in a SQLite-Database. My table has the following format:

**ID, Session, RightWrong**
1, 042102111244, 0
2, 042102111244, 1
3, 042102111244, 1
4, 042102111244, 1
5, 042102111244, 0
6, 042102111412, 0
7, 042102111412, 1
8, 042102111412, 0
9, 042102111412, 1

Where "session" refers to the time a certain quiz was *started*, and each row represents a single answer (0=Wrong answer, 1=Correct).

I only care about the "aggregate", i.e. how many questions were answered correctly (& out of how many questions) per quiz.

So my "dream" cursor would be:

**Session, RightAnswers, TotalNoOfQuestions**
042102111244, 3, 5
042102111412, 2, 4

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm having trouble figuring out a fitting query (which is admittedly less of a programming-problem than a logic-issue).

At the moment, I'm just reading all entries into a cursor
`Cursor cursor = db.query(MyDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);`
and thought that I would rather do some "post-processing", but am unsure what's the best approach.

Thanks for your help,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple raw query would be like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select session, sum(rightwrong) as RightAnswers, count(rightWrong) as TotalNoOfQuestions from tablename group by session");
```

You will use [Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to combine all rows with the same session together, then use the sum and count functions to figure out the breakdown within session. Note "sum" here only works because right answers are 1 and wrong answers are 0, if you change the way answers are recorded you will have to change the query a bit.

I'll try to guess how the db.query call would look:

```
String[] columns = {"Session", "sum(RightWrong) as RightAnswers", "count(RightWrong) as TotalNoOfQuestions";
String[] groupBy = {"Session"};


Cursor cursor = db.query("tablename", columns, null, null, groupBy, null, null);
```

I separated the String array declarations to clean it up a bit but I think that should function the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using group by clause.

You are using 
public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
            String orderBy)

ex. 
Cursor cursor = db.query(MyDataSQLHelper.TABLE, 
 new String[] {"Session", "sum(RightWrong) RightAnswers", "count(Session) TotalNoOfQuestions"},
null,
"Session",
null,
null);

You try again.